# In Outlook, how can I remove Calendars for multiple emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need only 1 Calendar: E2's (highlighted in light green). How can I remove all the others, if Outlook forbids me from using 'Delete Calendar'?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when the Delete command is grayed out, it means you can’t delete this calendar. According to [this official page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-a-calendar-9ba1364c-bdb0-41be-8f66-eaf96698d021) from MS, "any calendar you’ve created in Outlook can be deleted except the primary Outlook calendar". In your situation, it occurs to me that the calendars listed in your image are primary calendars of the email accounts configured in your Outlook. That's why the delete button is grayed out.

As a workaround, you may try using the [MFCMAPI tool](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) and set the display property of the calendars you want to delete to hidden so that these calendars will be invisible in Outlook:
[image]